# Usage of Hosted repo's in Nexus

Tags: repository, nexus, hosted

I need to use hosted repo's in nexus, in order to pull all the dependencies from the nexus. I have dependencies from different sources but I need all the dependencies pulled from nexus. I have created one hosted repo, but when I click the URL it shows

> "This maven2 hosted repository is not directly browseable at this
>   URL.
>
> Please use the component browser or asset browser to inspect the
>   contents of this repository."

Can you please explain descriptive steps to use host repo's in order to pull all the dependencies from the nexus.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to upload to the hosted repository all the dependencies you want to pull with the command `mvn deploy` as mentioned here - [Guide to deploying 3rd party JARs to remote repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html).

When you done to upload all your dependencies you can browse your components throught the UI in the `Search Components` box on the top. You can't browse the components in your repository from the url at this moment.